# Django MVC Philosophy and using get_object_404 instead of raise404

Tags: django, python-3.x, model-view-controller, web-development-server

I'm essentially confused about the motivation behind using `get_object_or_404()`.

When I was reading the Django docs, it said,

> Philosophy
>
> Why do we use a helper function `get_object_or_404()` instead of
>   automatically catching the `ObjectDoesNotExist` exceptions at a higher
>   level, or having the model API raise `Http404` instead of
>   `ObjectDoesNotExist?`
>
> Because that would couple the model layer to the view layer. One of
>   the foremost design goals of Django is to maintain loose coupling.
>   Some controlled coupling is introduced in the `django.shortcuts` module.

What do they mean when they say that it couples the "model layer to the view layer?" And how does it do so?

Comment: Well the model layer should not care about HTTP error codes that we raise (since the model should work independent from what the webserver exposes to the outside world). So at the model layer, one expects an `ObjectDoesNotExists`, whereas the view can trsnalate that in a 404. But since this is a very typical pattern, it is encapsulated anyway.